# Webserver to android XML parsing

Tags: android, xml, parsing, webserver

My dot-net web server is returning a XML. 
I want to show the data in an android app.

How to proceed?

I have a SOAP Class which gets the XML as response and returns the response. how to parse that response in a list view?

```
public String getAllDetails() {       
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    // Create the envelop.Envelop will be used to send the request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Says that the soap webservice is a .Net service
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    String s = "";       
    androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
    androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse(); 
        s = response.toString();           
        Log.d("Converter", response.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an XMLParser.java file that will enable you to parse your XML. Then use the respective methods to parse through your response XML output and show them either as a ListView, GridView, CardView etc. Refer to the code below, always works for me when it comes to parsing XML.

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
//** XML Output
//--------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Manchester United</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Barcelona</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Real Madrid</name>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Arsenal</name>
    </item>
</menu>

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//** list_item.xml
//--------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#dc6800"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//** main.xml
//--------------------------------------------------------------

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>


//--------------------------------------------------------------
//** XMLParser.java
//--------------------------------------------------------------

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
     * @param elem element
     */
    public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
        Node child;
        if( elem != null){
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                    if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     * @param Element node
     * @param key string
     * */
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
//** MainActivity.java
//--------------------------------------------------------------

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.foo.foo/foo/?format=xml"; // Your XML output
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME }, new int[] {
                R.id.name });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't working, first of all defaulthttpclient is not resolving but when i resolved it there is a strikeout on the classes and then the network part should be done on asyntask as the app crashes and logcat says android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. can u suggest something else

Comment: It's working for me ... Just ensure your XML comes back as a URL and parse it just like my example above.

Comment: my sdk version is the updated one..so its not working.. async task will do it.. ill check it then